# Is it possible to spoof the mac address of a wireless adapter so that windows sees the spoofed mac as the physical?

Tags: windows, wireless, mac-address, mac-spoofing

I know that its possible to spoof a mac address out to a network. But is it possible to spoof the address, so that the Windows operating system and applications running on Windows see a spoofed address as the physical address for the network card?

Answer (score 3):

Partially, yes. Windows OS (eg. using ipconfig command) sees the spoofed MAC address as the permanent MAC address.

However you can NOT say **all of the applications running on Windows** will see the spoofed one as the permanent one. Applications might be using some ways to acquire **the permanent (burned-in) MAC address** of the adapter. (For instance they might be using [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with OID_802_3_PERMANENT_ADDRESS option.) So some applications are harder to be fooled.

Comment: Actually, you could fully spoof the MAC address for all applications by running the system in a VM instead of running it on metal.

Comment: Yes, but application can also check if it is running on VM or not and deny if it is a VM.

Comment: That is not the question that was asked and that's actually a whole different subject.

Comment: My only issue with fully spoofing the mac in a VM is that I need to spoof the mac for a physical and specific type of adapter. Not just a generic virtual adapter, and I don't know if that is possible.